# Where does a WCF service hosted in a Windows Service read its config from?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, app-config

Library code normally reads the aspects of its `app.config` that is located where the executing/hosting assembly is. When a WCF service is hosted in a Windows Service, we have two executables: the WCF client, and the Windows Service.

And in during debugging if seen it looking for a lot of other strange executables. So, where is my WCF supposed to have its `app.config` file?

Comment: Is the WCF service in a class library referenced by the windows service?

Comment: Yes, @alexw, it is, and of course referenced by it's clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be looking at

> YourServiceName.exe.config

in the deployed folder.

Comment: The folder in what is deployed? Both the client of the WCF service and its  host Windows Service are running executables at any time app.config is examined, and when neither .exe is running, and I try a unit or so, I get some very funny .exe paths.

Comment: The folder on the system where you installed the windows service. The other way of looking at it would be right click on the service in "services" and look at executable path.